# In Python, how do I make a decorator class with a method that has the same signature as the function it wraps?

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-3.10, pylance

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```py
from typing import Callable, Generic, ParamSpec, TypeVar

t_Params = ParamSpec("t_Params")
t_Ret = TypeVar("t_Ret")
class Wraps(Generic[t_Params, t_Ret]):

    _func: Callable[t_Params, t_Ret]

    def __call__(self, func: Callable[t_Params, t_Ret]):
        self._func = func
        return self

    def call(self, *args: t_Params.args, **kwargs: t_Params.kwargs) -> t_Ret:
        return self._func(*args, **kwargs)

@Wraps()
def rep(a: str, b: int, **kwargs):
    return a * b
```

I don't want to use `__init__` to set `self._func` because I would not be able to pass other arguments into `__init__`.

I would expect the `__call__` method to infer the type of `t_Params` and `t_Ret`, but it does not:

```py
# mousing over `rep` and `rep.func` shows:

rep      # (function) rep: Wraps[(*args: Unknown, **kwargs: Unknown), Unknown]
rep.func # (method) call: (...) -> Unknown
```

I believe this is because the types aren't being inferred when the class instance is created, but rather when the instance is called.

I want the `Wraps.call` method to have the same signature as the wrapped function. Is there any way to do this?

---

Editing to update with progress:

If I move away from `__call__` being what defines the generic types for the class instance, I make an alternate constructor that feeds all of its arguments to `__init__` after the `func` argument. However, I can't give the alternate constructor (`.new`) the correct type hint.

```py
from typing import Callable, Generic, TypeVar

t_WrapsCallable = TypeVar("t_WrapsCallable", contravariant=True, bound=Callable)
t_Callable = TypeVar("t_Callable", bound=Callable)

class Wraps(Generic[t_WrapsCallable]):

    func: t_WrapsCallable

    def __init__(self, func: t_WrapsCallable):
        self.func = func
        return self

    @classmethod
    def new(cls, *args, **kwargs) -> Callable[[t_Callable], "Wraps[t_Callable]"]:
        def _new(func: t_Callable) -> Wraps[t_Callable]:
            return cls(func, *args, **kwargs)
        return _new

@Wraps.new()
def rep(a: str, b: int):
    return a * b

rep      # (function) rep: Wraps[(a: str, b: int) -> str]
rep.func # (variable) func: (a: str, b: int) -> str

class WrapsWithName(Wraps[t_WrapsCallable]):

    def __init__(self, func: t_WrapsCallable, name: str):
        super().__init__(func)
        self.name = name

    @classmethod
    def new(cls, name: str) -> Callable[[t_Callable], "WrapsWithName[t_Callable]"]:
        # The following line has a type issue:
        # Function return type "Wraps[t_Callable@new]" is incompatible with type "WrapsWithName[t_Callable@new]"
        #   "Wraps[t_Callable@new]" is incompatible with "WrapsWithName[t_Callable@new]"
        return super().new(name)

@WrapsWithName.new("repeat")
def rep2(a: str, b: int):
    return a * b

rep2      # (function) rep2: WrapsWithName[(a: str, b: int) -> str]
rep2.func # (variable) func: (a: str, b: int) -> str
rep2.name # (variable) name: str
```

I can't nest `Generic`s, or the `.new` function would return something like `Callable[[t_Callable], Self[t_Callable]]` where Self is a TypeVar that binds to the self's class.

This brings me to an alternate question: Is there a way around Python's lack of support for higher-kinded-types?